# Relative line numbers for monaco editor

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

Monaco Editor offers VIM key bindings. I also want to make the line numbers relative when using the VIM mode. Is there any API in the `monaco` global object which I can use to achieve this?

**Note**: I don't own the code base. I want to use this in a website that already has a monaco editor instance.

I went through the global object and could not find anything useful.

```
[
    "create",
    "onDidCreateEditor",
    "createDiffEditor",
    "createDiffNavigator",
    "createModel",
    "setModelLanguage",
    "setModelMarkers",
    "getModelMarkers",
    "onDidChangeMarkers",
    "getModels",
    "getModel",
    "onDidCreateModel",
    "onWillDisposeModel",
    "onDidChangeModelLanguage",
    "createWebWorker",
    "colorizeElement",
    "colorize",
    "colorizeModelLine",
    "tokenize",
    "defineTheme",
    "setTheme",
    "remeasureFonts",
    "registerCommand",
    "AccessibilitySupport",
    "ContentWidgetPositionPreference",
    "CursorChangeReason",
    "DefaultEndOfLine",
    "EditorAutoIndentStrategy",
    "EditorOption",
    "EndOfLinePreference",
    "EndOfLineSequence",
    "MinimapPosition",
    "MouseTargetType",
    "OverlayWidgetPositionPreference",
    "OverviewRulerLane",
    "RenderLineNumbersType",
    "RenderMinimap",
    "ScrollbarVisibility",
    "ScrollType",
    "TextEditorCursorBlinkingStyle",
    "TextEditorCursorStyle",
    "TrackedRangeStickiness",
    "WrappingIndent",
    "InjectedTextCursorStops",
    "PositionAffinity",
    "ConfigurationChangedEvent",
    "BareFontInfo",
    "FontInfo",
    "TextModelResolvedOptions",
    "FindMatch",
    "ApplyUpdateResult",
    "EditorType",
    "EditorOptions"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set `lineNumbers` to `"relative"`.

```js
monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
  value: `function x() {
  console.log("Hello world!");
}`,
  language: 'javascript',
  theme: 'vs-dark',
  lineNumbers: 'relative'
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" data-name="vs/editor/editor.main" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.26.1/min/vs/editor/editor.main.min.css">
<div id="container" style="height:400px;border:1px solid black;"></div>
<script>var require = { paths: { 'vs': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.26.1/min/vs' } }</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.26.1/min/vs/loader.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.26.1/min/vs/editor/editor.main.nls.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.26.1/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js"></script>
```

Given that you want to dynamically change the options and you probably don't have access to the editor instance, you can find the active editors on the page using the global `monaco` object with `monaco.editor.getEditors()`, which returns an array of all active instances, then use `updateOptions()` to customize the line numbers.

In your case it'd look something like:

```js
// anywhere in the JS code
monaco.editor.getEditors()[0].updateOptions({
  lineNumbers: 'relative'
});
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I have mentioned in the note that have to change this setting at runtime ie., after creating the editor instance. I only have access to the `monaco` global object in the browser console.  There is an editor created already with few other settings, and I want to change only this relative line setting.

Comment: Thanks. This works in the monaco editor playground website and should be the accepted answer. However, when I tried to do in [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-palindrome/), it doesnt work.  Maybe this is only in newer versions of monaco-editor or one can choose to expose this method in the global object?

Comment: @VishnuvardhanS perhaps it wasn't in that monaco version or was intentionally removed? It's on the latest [docs](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.editor.html#getEditors).

Comment: Yeah, the later sounds convincing to me. Thanks for the response.